# como passar dados para uma funcao php pela url ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Pessoal tentem me dar uma força por aqui, já procurei e não achei uma resposta que me atenda.

Vamos lá!

Estou trabalhando com classes em php, gostaria de passar dados de um formulário através de ajax.
Porem tenho duvidas na execução da URL, eu não sei como ela irá ficar.

```
$.ajax({
     type:'post',
     url:'DUVIDAAAA',
     ajax:'1',
     success: function (data){
          alert(data)
     }
});
```

Na minha url eu preciso entrar na minha classe PHP ! porem se eu colocar um caminho direto ela entra mas da erro pq a classe instanciada nao foi solicitada.

Eu chamo minhas classes com um autoload.

Comment: Muito obscuro ainda. Qual é o problema, especificamente?

Comment: O url será onde o POST/GET existirá. Se criar biscoito.php e dentro dele `$_POST['bolacha']` o URL deve ser http://seu-site.com/biscoito.php.

Comment: URL deve ser a pagina para onde você vai enviar os dados...

Comment: Eu preciso acessar meu arquivo class.php e nele acessar a funcao que eu quero

Comment: @PedroSoares na URL voce coloca a URL que seu sistema teria se fosse acessar a classe/metodo...

Comment: sim mas meu problema esta sendo assim, eu ate passo os valores pra classe mas la ele fica perdido, existe uma maneira de eu passar pela URL tbm uma fora de ja definir qual funcao aqueles dados vao ? @RafaelAcioly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sei q a pergunta é antiga e vc já deve ter se dado conta do que precisa fazer, mas pra caso alguém chegue aqui e queira saber uma resposta, segue a minha.

Fragmento de código javascript usando ajax do jquery:

```
    $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'test.php',
              data: {

                  variavel1: 'algumvalor',
                  variavel2: 'outrovalor',
              },
              success: function(data) 
              {
                alert(data);
              }
            });
```

Na página test.php :

```
<?php

//Essa classe abaixo deve ficar em outro arquivo e ser chamada nessa página

class Teste
{
    function exemplo($a, $b)
    {
        // Faz um processamento qualquer com os parâmetros informados e dá um retorno
        return 'O valor de A é ' . $a . ' e o valor de B é '. $b;
    }
}


$var1 = $_POST["variavel1"];
$var2 = $_POST["variavel2"];

//Instancia sua classe e passa as variáveis pra algum método ou
// no construtor se esse aceitar parâmetros

$teste = new Teste();

$retorno = $teste->exemplo($var1, $var2);

echo $retorno; // Isso irá voltar na chamada ajax e o alert do javascript irá exibir na tela
```

Comment: Nem lembrava mais dessa pergunta, mas hoje sei exatamente o que fazer. Porém mesmo respondendo agora a sua resposta foi bem completa. Dá pra tratar um pouco o código mas é exatamente esse o caminho. Com certeza vai ajudar pessoas iniciando com requisições Ajax com jquery. Obrigado pela sua resposta

Comment: Tá certo! Obrigado, abração. :D