# Como colocar o valor de um campo adquirido com jquery em php?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Quero fazer uma verificação tento como parâmetro a data de um datepicker e o id de um item.

```
        <script>
            $('.menu-item').click(function() {  

              var item = $(this).attr('value');
              alert(item);
            });
        </script>

         <script>
        $("#delivery_time").click(function() {   

            $.ajax
                    ({
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $("#oi").html("Carregando...");
                        },
                        success: function ()
                        {

                            var datahora = $("#delivery_date").val();
                            <?php 

                            //Conexao ao banco e contator 
                                    $conecta = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","alugaq")or die("Erro ao conectar!");
                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'mt_order' WHERE 'merchant_id' LIKE '%$merchant_id%' AND 'item_id' LIKE '%$item%' AND 'delivery_date' LIKE '%$data%'" ;
                                    $query = mysqli_query($conecta,$sql);
                                    $qtd = mysqli_num_rows($query);       
                            ?>
                            alert($(".ui-state-default:contains('00')").css('display','none'));
                            alert(datahora);
                            alert(item);
                            alert(<?php echo $qtd ;?>);

                        }


                    });


    });
    </script>
```

Eu preciso que a variável item e a variável datahora funcionem na query, mas não sei colocar as variáveis do javaScript no php.

Comment: Não cara, vc não pode usar php assim dentro do javascript, o que vc tem que fazer é passar uma variável pra uma página php via ajax e pegar o retorno.

Comment: Olha, dois exemplos de ajax em respostas que dei uns dias atrás, talvez te ajude:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109904/como-passar-dados-para-uma-funcao-php-pela-url-ajax/173967#173967
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170469/filtro-c-ajax-php/170723#170723

Comment: Depois que a página é enviada, o javascript se encontra no browser da pessoa e não tem como rodar php lá. Por isso o ajax envia o dado pro servidor e pega um resultado de volta pra ser usado no javascript que está rodando no browser.

Comment: jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. ESSe foi o erro que deu ao tentar

Comment: Isso aí é um aviso.  Envia essa var item por ajax para um if(isset($_post['item'])) e lá defina ela na  query, pega o retorno e exiba da forma que quiser. Retorno só vem em forma de texto.