# include com parâmetro?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Existe include com parâmetro?

Tenho uma pagina `.php` que contem o seguinte código:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#segunda">Segunda-Feira</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#terca">Ter&ccedil;a-Feira</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#quarta">Quarta-Feira</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="quinta">Quinta-feira</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sexta">Sexta-feira</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sabado">S&aacute;bado</a></li>
</ul>
```

A classe nav nav-tabs forma 6 abas e em cada ABA mostro os horários do FULANINHO.

- Na ABA SEGUNDA-FEIRA mostro os horários de segunda do FULANINHO
- Na ABA TERÇA-FEIRA mostro os horários de terça do FULANINHO
- E assim sucessivamente.

Quando comecei a fazer o código vi que seria uma repetição de tudo, onde só mudaria o dia da semana e o nome do FULANINHO que vem da pagina anterior via POST.

Então pensei em algo do tipo `include('segunda.php',$id_fulaninho)`. 
Isso é possível?

Se não, teria alguma forma que ainda desconheço *(sou novo no* `php`) de reduzir essa quantidade absurda de código **repetido**?

Comment: faça o include e no include set o horário e o nome do Fulaninho ou o horário e o nome do Ciclaninho etc... de acordo do que vem do post. Para podermos ajudar seria bom postar o codigo da pagina anterior do post e do include e de que forma se obtém os dados do fulaninho, etc..

Comment: Por quê você não encapsula o código em uma função que recebe os parâmetros e, ao invés de dar o `include` para exibir o HTML, você inclui o arquivo com a função e a chama onde deseja exibir o resultado.

Comment: Bom dia Leo Caracciolo e Anderson Carlos... Obrigado pela atenção de vocês.  Como disse sou novo no dialeto "peagapes" ;) Vou estudar suas palavras com atenção e tentar fazer o que vocês indicaram :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe [include](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php) com paramento, mas, pude perceber na sua pergunta que é fácil isso, um ***exemplo*** para ilustrar:

Crie o arquivo que vai ser incluindo no outro:

*Nome do arquivo:* `_id.php`

```
<?php

    echo $id;
```

depois crie o arquivo com esse [include](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php):

*Nome do arquivo:* `vid.php`

```
<?php

    $id = 100;
    include('_id.php');
```

dessa forma o arquivo `_id.php` tem o acesso a variável `$id` e seu valor pode ser utilizado tranquilamente, igual e parecido com o que você pretende nas suas **abas**.

Vale lembrar que o [include](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php) pode ser utilizado com o protocolo [HTTP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) e ai passando paramentos na url:

```
<?php
    include('http://www.example.com/s.php?id=100');
```

mas, se o arquivo fizer parte do seu projeto (*no mesmo sistemas de arquivos*), não aceita parâmetros.

***Referencias***

- [PHP - function include](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php)
- [Hypertext Transfer Protocol](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss se já percebeu que a única solução plausíveis são as suas, poxa se comenta no post de todo mundo está se tornando um cara chato na rede.

Comment: Como você disse opinião... A sua dica também acho ruim por vários fatores, mas, não vem ao caso. Se você tem uma resposta melhor poste e seja agraciado com os votos e aceitação é assim que a maioria se comporta, agora a todo momento fica dizendo faz isso ou aquilo está se tornando chato a situação. @AndersonCarlosWoss obrigado.

Comment: Bom dia Virgilio Novic.. Obrigado pela sua atenção. Também agradeço você compartilhar seu conhecimento com todos. Vou ler com atenção todas as resposta com MUITA atenção . Sei que o mundo é redondo e existem vários caminhos para se chegar ao mesmo lugar.  Tenho certeza que sua resposta funciona. Mas tenho que estudar e entender. Como já comentei algumas vezes neste post sou novo nesse negocio de php :)

Comment: Claro @RicardoM.Souza, essa solução foi dado num contexto da sua pergunta, ou seja, vai depender e muito como é o contexto geral da sua aplicação, talvez possa utilizar outras técnicas e/ou outras formas, a resposta em questão foi a primeira que vi mediante o que você questionou, mas, pode perguntar se tiver alguma duvida pertinente, estou aqui e pode pergunta ... Obrigado ... também

Comment: Boa tarde @Virgilio.  Cara fiz como tu falou e ficou 1000% :).  Na realidade o que ocorreu é que eu até então pensava que as variáveis que vinham da tela anterior através do post NÃO poderiam ser lidas dentro de um arquivo INCLUDE no meio da pagina php.  Outra coisa que estava PENSANDO errado e que cada arquivo INCLUDE dentro da pagina <html></html> NÃO se comunicaria com outro. Tipo se eu tenho include(AA.php) e nesse arquivo crio a variavel $dia, eu pensava que no arquivo include(BB.php) que fica 20 linhas abaixo do include AA.php o arquivo BB.php NÃO leria a variavel $dia.Novamente OBRIGADO

Comment: OK @RicardoM.Souza era nesses aspecto que eu queria que você chegasse e entendesse, com isso você mesmo pode propor coisas melhores no seu código, mas, com esse conhecimento prévio. Se essa resposta te serviu e quiser marca como resposta da sua pergunta aceite como resposta!

Comment: Cara na hora que li.. já marquei.. :) digo já dei o voto ... mas marcar como resposta.. eu realmente TAMBÉM NÃO tinha percebido até agora :)... Vou marcar a sua e a do Antonio Alexandre.  Também testei do jeito que ele mencionou e funcionou beleza.  Só que do jeito que tu explicou é muito mais prático neste momento.  Outra coisa que acabei de aprender é para que serve o ARROBA na frente do nome :). Poxa.. só da para colocar uma como resposta a pergunta... :( Marquei a Sua.  Fico devendo para o Antonio Alexandre :)

Comment: Só para complementar :) Nem sabia que aqui tinha CHAT.  Apareceu uma mensagem dizendo para evitar discuções extensas e se eu gostaria de mover para o chat.. Não as movi para o chat pois acho que são informações relevantes e creio que no chat tais informações ficariam restritas a nos dois. Abraços :)

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro a seguinte solução:

Criar uma função para receber os dois parâmetros e retornar o output html desejado.

Ex:

Função getHorarios.php

```
<?php

function getHorarios($dia_semana, $id_pessoa)
{
    $html_output = '';

    /*
    // .= concatena strings
    $html_output.= '10:00 - Alguma coisa. <br>';
    $html_output.= '12:00 - Outra  coisa. <br>';
    */

    return $html_output;
}
```

ajaxHorarios.php - Exemplo de chamada da função:

```
<?php

    require('getHorarios.php');

    if( !empty($_POST["dia_semana"]) && !empty($_POST["id_pessoa"] )
    {
        $dia_semana = $_POST["dia_semana"];
        $id_pessoa  = $_POST["id_pessoa"];

        echo getHorarios($dia_semana, $id_pessoa);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Erro';
    }
```

Pras chamadas ajax:
[como passar dados para uma funcao php pela url ajax?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109904/como-passar-dados-para-uma-funcao-php-pela-url-ajax/173967#173967)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss boa dica. Já conhecia e já usei muito a função empty, mas não tinha me ligado que ela podia ser utilizada no lugar de isset. Obrigado. Alterei o exemplo.

Comment: Bom dia Antonio Alexandre.. Obrigado por compartilhar sua resposta :). Eu entendi o que a função GETHORAIOS faz.e o AjaxHorarios.php tambem.. O lance de chamar a função ajax eu ate já fiz e ficou legal :). Agora.. tudo junto do jeito que tu sugeriu ainda não tinha visto este modo pela falta de experiencia. Obrigado mesmo.. Vou passar o dia de hoje estudando e compreendendo seu exemplo.